# How to monkey-patch a function declared inside another function

Tags: javascript, monkeypatching

Say I have the following code:

```js
window.foo = function() {
  bar();
  function bar() {
    console.log('hello');
  }
}
/* insert monkey-patching code here */
foo();
```

What code can I replace `/* insert monkey-patching code here */` with in order to make this e.g. write `goodbye` instead of `hello` on the console?

I have tried the following in order to override `bar`, but it does not work:

```js
window.foo = function() {
  bar();
  function bar() {
    console.log('hello');
  }
}
window.bar = function() {
  console.log('goodbye');
}
window.foo.bar = function() {
  console.log('goodbye');
}
foo();
```

Comment: It's not possible. The inner function is no longer reachable through the namespace of the outer scope. It is essentially protected by closure.

Comment: `log = console.log; console.log = () => log('goodbye')` It's probably not what you're looking for, though, since what you're asking for is *generally* impossible. You might be able to find loopholes like what I posted in some situations only.

Comment: You won't be able to override `bar` outside of `foo` as calling `bar()` will always look in the current scope first. In this case, it will always call `function bar() { console.log('hello'); }`

Comment: The only way is to completely override the foo object, but this is not what you want. `window.foo = function() { console.log('Goodbye'); }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't.

The function is stored in a local variable inside `foo`. It isn't accessible from outside that function.

You would need to either:

- Replace the whole of `foo`
- Refactor `foo` so `bar` was declared in a wider scope (and accessible from where you want to change it)